# xml parser with curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

i have  made a curl script that parses xml url using curl like below

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://www.slideshare.net/api/2/search_slideshows?api_key=OKlHvfPo&ts=1320522764&hash=12bf522db6f39d8f96ec3d9187a88e32b02205a8&q=electrical+engineering&page=4&download=0&items_per_page=25';

echo $url;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');

$query = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$array = (array) simplexml_load_string($query);

//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($array);

foreach ($array as $key) {
    echo $key['Title']. "<br>";
}
?>
```

The array $array is printed very perfactely but how to itrate this array i am not understanding. because foreach loop as i used is not working. it gives only two empty resutls. please help

Comment: Please post the output of `print_r($array)`. I suspect what you need is `foreach ($array as $key=>$value)`

Comment: Array
    (
    [Meta] => SimpleXMLElement Object
     (
      [Query] => electrical engineering
       [ResultOffset] => SimpleXMLElement Object
       (
         )

        [NumResults] => 25
         [TotalResults] => 36839
        )

    [Slideshow] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [ID] => id value
                    [Title] => title value
                    [Description] => descript
                    [Status] => 2
                    
                    
                   )

Comment: Not here please, edit your question with this array in properly formatted code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplexml requires a reference to file buffer. Read curl_setopt, specifically CURLOPT_FILE.
curl_exec returns (true/false). You most certainly do not want that.

Here is a perl example of how to use buffers with curl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my $curl = new WWW::Curl::Easy;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
$::errbuf="";
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, "::errbuf");

my $response_body;
open (my $fileb, ">", \$response_body);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,$fileb);
my $retcode;
(($retcode = $curl->perform) == 0) and do {
    # do something with $response_body
}
```

Perl and PHP are similar, you should get the idea.

Comment: i am not understanding. can you modifiy my code which i can use in my script directly

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
Specifically, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#98491 gives a good example of how to buffer the input.
Then do `simplexml_load_string($this->responseXML)`.

Comment: It really is a classic case of failure to RTFM before using the function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foreach ($array['ResultOffset'] as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ' -> ' . $val;
}
```

Edit:

You must remove the (array) type casting of simplexml_load_string. It should already be an iteratable object.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($query);
foreach ($xml as $element) {
    if ($element->children()) {
        foreach ($element->children() as $el) {
            echo $el;
        }
    } else {
        echo $element;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working. this giving an error "invalid argument supplied for foreach"